# Proving $A^\ast = A$ on a given set

Tags: sets, kleene-star

I am working on some set theory and am trying to prove how a set can have the property $A^* = A$.

For set $A=\{0^n1^n \mid n \ge0\}$, I still do not understand exactly what $A^*$ is. For example, I thought $A^*$ is the enumeration of the set $A$ so

$A^* = \{\epsilon,01,0011,000111,00001111,....\}$

Any helping in at least understanding what $A^*$ is for this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\{0^n1^n \mid n \ge0\}$ is exactly $\{\epsilon,01,0011,000111,00001111,\cdots\}$.

Comment: Can you confirm $A^*$ is the Kleenen star of $A$ _in the question_?

Comment: Your set doesn't satisfy $A^*=A$.

Comment: If you are searching from some set $A$ satisfying $A=A^*$, try choosing $A=B^*$ for any $B$. Further, not all sets $A$ satisfy $A=A^*$, e.g. $A=\{0\}$ is surely different from $A^* = \{\epsilon,0,00,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 2):

What you have written (i.e., $\{ \varepsilon, 01, 0011, 000111, \ldots \}$) is simply *$A$ itself*.

(Assuming $A^\ast$ is the Kleene star operation) you cannot prove $A = A^\ast$ because **it is not correct**.

The Kleene star $A^\ast$ is defined as the union of the powers $A^i$, where $A^0 = \{ \varepsilon \}$ and $A^{i+1} = A^i \cdot A = \{ w \cdot w' \mid w \in A^i, w' \in A \}$. An inductive argument easily shows:
$$A^i = \{ w_1 \cdots w_i \mid w_1, \ldots, w_i \in A \}
= \{ 0^{n_1} 1^{n_1} \cdots 0^{n_i} 1^{n_i} \mid n_1, \ldots, n_i \ge 0 \}$$

Since $A^\ast$ is the union over all such $A^i$, we obtain
$$A^\ast
= \{ 0^{n_1} 1^{n_1} \cdots 0^{n_i} 1^{n_i} \mid i, n_1, \ldots, n_i \ge 0 \},$$
which is obviously *not* equal to $A$.

Comment: Yeah the * was in fact the Kleen star and I can easily disprove this with a counter example.